TypeORM: Custom Many to Many relations don't populate all the way through
I've made a custom many to many relation between Business and Salesperson, via a joint table BusinessSalesperson. Here is my current code
    Business


    @OneToMany(() => BusinessSalesperson, (bsp) => bsp.business, {
        nullable: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    salespersons: Salesperson[]

    Salesperson

    @OneToMany(() => BusinessSalesperson, (bsp) => bsp.salesperson, {
        nullable: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    business: Business[]
    
    BusinessSalesperson

    @ManyToOne(() => Salesperson, (sp) => sp.business, {
        eager: true,
        nullable: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'salespersonid' })
    salesperson: Salesperson

    @ManyToOne(() => Business, (b) => b.salespersons, {
        eager: true,
        nullable: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'businessid' })
    business: Business;

And in my service, I call this
        const businesses = this.dataSource.createEntityManager().find(Business, {relations: {salespersons: true, businessSalespersons: { salesperson: true} } });

I try to get the salesperson and businessSalesperson because my salespersons relation was giving me an array of businessSalespersons.
In my results, strangely, I receive hydrated Business, but not my Salesperson
Business {
                     |   businessid: 1365991,
                     |   companyLegalName: 'SCG',
                     |   businessName: 'SCG',
                     |   salespersons: [
                     |     BusinessSalesperson {
                     |       salespersonId: 549,
                     |       businessId: 1365991,
                     |       administrator: false,
                     |       salesperson: null,
                     |       business: [Business]
                     |     }
                     |   ],
                     |   businessSalespersons: [
                     |     BusinessSalesperson {
                     |       salespersonId: 549,
                     |       businessId: 1365991,
                     |       administrator: false,
                     |       salesperson: null,
                     |       business: [Business]
                     |     }
                     |   ]
                     | }

What am I doing wrong here ?

So, answering my own question if anyone end up in the same case:
I had to add a
referencedColumnName: 'salespersonId'

to my JoinColumn on Salesperson. I guess because of the architecture and naming of the db, TypeOrm was unsure of what to do, and needed more specs.
